# подскажите регулярку которая проверят что два слова записаны через пробел?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите регулярку, которая проверит, что по крайней мере два слова записаны через пробел

**Пример валидных:**

```
Иван Иванович 

Ghghhg ghghgh

прпр прпрпр прпрпр
```

**Пример невалидных:**

```
прпрпрпр
```

Comment: только один пробел или может быть несколько?

Comment: SO вам не фабрика по производству регулярных выражений. Если вы продолжите игнорировать старания участников сообщества и не принимать их ответы- вас ожидают плохие последствия.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const regEx = /[^\s]+\s[^\s]+/

console.log(regEx.test('q qewrqewrew'));
console.log(regEx.test('q qewrqew rew'));
console.log(regEx.test('qqewrew'));
console.log(regEx.test('q  qewrqewrew'));  // два пробела поэтому false
```

где: 
`[^\s]+` - любой символ кроме пробела повторяющий один и более раз 
`\s` - сам пробел

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regEx = /.+( .+)+/;

console.log(regEx.test('Иван Иванович'));      // true
console.log(regEx.test('Ghghhg ghghgh'));      // true
console.log(regEx.test('прпр прпрпр прпрпр')); // true
console.log(regEx.test('прпрпрпр'));           // false
```

Немного строже, указываем конкретные символы, которые ожидаем:

```js
const regEx = /[a-zа-яё]+( [a-zа-яё]+)+/i;

console.log(regEx.test('Иван Иванович'));      // true
console.log(regEx.test('Ghghhg ghghgh'));      // true
console.log(regEx.test('прпр прпрпр прпрпр')); // true
console.log(regEx.test('прпрпрпр'));           // false
```